# Are there memory leaks in ElasticSearch's TransportClient 5.4.3 or is my code flawed?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, memory, groovy, memory-leaks

Are there memory leaks in ElasticSearch's TransportClient 5.4.3? Or am I not using and closing the objects correctly?

I'm using the client in a Jenkins (2.68) which is on JRE 1.8.0_66 and writing my code in Groovy. `BulkRequestBuilder` is being used to submit multiple records.

Throughout the code, these 4x 16 MB byte arrays appear in memory but never get closed even past the TransportClient.close() method:
[image: 4x 16 MB byte arrays]
If I step through the code more slowly, I can get up to 9x of these 16 MB bytes arrays, some of which look very similar:
[image: 7x 16MB byte arrays]

I believes I'm following the official documentation fully: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html

Here's a trimmed down version of the code I'm using:

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab(group = "org.apache.logging.log4j", module = "log4j-api", version = "2.8.2", initClass = true),
    @Grab(group = "org.apache.logging.log4j", module = "log4j-core", version = "2.8.2", initClass = true),
    @Grab(group = "org.elasticsearch.client", module = "transport", version = "5.4.3", initClass = true)
])
public class ElasticSearchReport implements Serializable {

    pubblic void execute() {
        // Data to report.
        List<Map<String, Object>> data = ...

        // ElasticSearch settings. Do not use sniffing because we want to upload data to the master node.
        Settings settings = Settings.builder()
            .put("cluster.name", "my-cluster")
            .put("client.transport.sniff", false)
            .build()

        PreBuiltTransportClient preBuiltTransportClient = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
        TransportClient client = preBuiltTransportClient.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("my-elastic-search-host"), 9300))
        List<String> errors = new LinkedList<String>()

        try {
            BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk()

            // Build the bulk query with each data entry.
            data.each({entry ->
                String serialisedEntry = SerializationUtils.toJson(entry)
                bulkRequest.add(client.prepareIndex("my-index", "my-type").setSource(serialisedEntry, XContentType.JSON))
            })

            // Process the response.
            bulkRequest.get().getItems().each({response ->
                if (response.failed) {
                    errors.add(response.failure.message)
                    return
                }

                final String statusName = response.status().name()

                // Check statusName ...
            })

            if (errors) throw new Exception(...)
        } finally {
            client.close()
            preBuiltTransportClient.close()
        }
    }
}
```

From the objects I'm using, only `PreBuiltTransportClient` and `TransportClient` implement `Closeable` so I'm trying to explicitly close them in my `finally` block.

Tried using `.withCloseable()` (Groovy's equivalent to `try-with-resources`) but it did not prevent the issue from happening.

I thought perhaps my `bulkRequest.get().getItems().each({response ->` line was doing something funny so I replaced it with the following but to no effect:

```
BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequest.get()
BulkItemResponse[] bulkItemResponses = bulkResponse.getItems()
for (int responseIndex = 0; responseIndex < bulkItemResponses.length; responseIndex++) { ... }
```

I've also tried replacing `BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequest.get()` with `BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequest.execute().actionGet()` with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ElasticSearch Java REST Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/index.html) doesn't appear to have these issues.
I've switched over to it and haven't experienced out-of-memory errors. All relatively large byte arrays are released once the client is closed and scoped out.